# The formula for pitch circle diameter.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]

I want to put $n$ number of circle with $r$ radius each in a big circle. Want to calculate the radius $R$ of the big circle. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can take $R$ as large as you like, so the question is not well defined. Do you want to take $R$ as small as possible without the $n$ small circles of radius $r$ overlapping?

Comment: What are the constraints on the big circle? Do you want the small ones to touch each other and be equidistributed?

Comment: I think he means all the circles touch the parent circle and also touch the adjacent circles. So all the smaller circles will be along the circumference of the bigger circle.

Comment: yes i want R as small as possible without overlapping the small circle

Answer (score 2):

Consider a regular $n$-gon centered at the origin and with side length $2r$.  Then the vertices are the centers of the $n$ small circles, and the distance $\rho$ from the center to a vertex is given by the relationship $\sin \frac{\pi}{n} = \frac{r}{\rho}$.  Hence $$R = \rho + r = r\left( 1 + \csc \frac{\pi}{n} \right).$$